# Where is Spark driver when you submit SparkApplication using databricks-connect?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, databricks-connect

I'm using an private server to submit some jobs on databricks using **databricks-connect**.
Where is host Spark driver ? On private server and it just sends jobs to databricks worker ?
I'm able to see .show() results directly on my server, what does it mean ? Am I using **client mode**, and spark driver stay on private server ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Databricks Connect, the machine where it's installed is the Spark Driver, and Spark Executors are in your Data Plane.